# Ora library doesn't compile with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, spinner

I am trying to build a CLI with nodejs and i tried to add some spinners in the command line using Ora. Unfortunately when i run tsc to build my JS 26 errors are thrown :

```
........ 
node_modules/ora/index.d.ts:269:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

269  frame(): string;
            ~

node_modules/ora/index.d.ts:270:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

270 }
    ~


Found 26 errors.
```

**this my tsconfig file :**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2017", "es2015", "dom", "es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src/**.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I tried importing the module in multiple ways but it always seems to fail the build. thank you.